# Interact with Dropdown with a "nesty-input" class using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate complaints with the FCC. I'm having trouble interacting with a dropdown box located at https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=39744 . The element is the ***Phone Issues*** dropdown box:

[image]

The HTML is:

```html
<div class="form-field string  required  request_custom_fields_22619354" >
  <label id="request_custom_fields_22619354_label" for="request_custom_fields_22619354">Phone Issues</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="request[custom_fields][22619354]" id="request_custom_fields_22619354" autocomplete="off" data-tagger="[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;-&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Unwanted Calls (including do not call and spoofing)&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;telemarketing_phone&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Junk Faxes&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;junk_faxes_phone&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Availability&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;availability_phone&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Billing&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;billing_phone&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Cramming (unauthorized charges on your phone bill)&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;cramming_phone&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Equipment&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;equipment_phone&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Interference&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;interference_phone&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Number Portability (keeping your number if you change providers)&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;number_portability_phone&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Privacy&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;privacy_phone&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Rural Call Completion&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;rural_call_completion_phone&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Slamming (change of your carrier without permission)&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;slamming_phone&quot;}]" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="request_custom_fields_22619354_hint" aria-labelledby="request_custom_fields_22619354_label" />

  <p id="request_custom_fields_22619354_hint">Please select the issue that best describes your complaint.</p>
</div>
```

I want to select index 1 or the text *Unwanted Calls (including do not call and spoofing)*. (Index 0 is the text with the dash).

Here are my three attempts, but they are producing exceptions:

```py
dropdown_issue = driver.find_element_by_id("request_custom_fields_22619354")

# First try - ElementNotInteractableException
dropdown_issue.send_keys("Unwanted Calls");

# Second try - ElementNotInteractableException
dropdown_issue.send_keys(Keys.DOWN);
dropdown_issue.send_keys(Keys.DOWN);
dropdown_issue.send_keys(Keys.ENTER);

# Third try - 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_index'
dropdown_issue.select_by_index(1)
```

I think I need to go up to the "nesty-input", which has the down arrow (but no name or id). I am not sure how to access the nesty-input.

How do I select the desired index for the dropdown control?

Comment: I dont have experience with this nesty-input, but I would try `ActionChains` along with `move_to_element` then `move_by_offset` to tackle this

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Use `WebDriverWait` to make sure element visible and use `Select` to handle dropdown.

You need wait until this is element visible:

```
By.XPATH -> //label[text()="Phone Issues"]//following-sibling::a[@class="nesty-input ae-exclude"]
```

And the `select element` is:

```
By.ID -> ae-request_custom_fields_22619354
```

Please try the below code:

```
driver.get('https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=39744')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//label[text()="Phone Issues"]//following-sibling::a[@class="nesty-input ae-exclude"]')))
elmt = driver.find_element_by_id('ae-request_custom_fields_22619354')
select = Select(elmt)
select.select_by_index(1)

#select by other method
select.select_by_value('telemarketing_phone')
select.select_by_visible_text('Unwanted Calls (including do not call and spoofing)')
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right about some of the elements - they need to be enabled. I'm finding the `ae-*` elements are activated based on a previous element. I also need to insert a delay with `time.sleep(randint(2, 4))`. Otherwise, an `ae-*` elements may not have been enabled when I try to `send_keys` to it.

Comment: @jww glad it worked, but I think I've found better approach, please looks the updated answer. I'm using `WebDriverWait` instead `time.sleep` you mean and I've updated the locator for wait. Hope this help more.

Comment: It looks like I should delete the question. The community found it to be sub-par. Do you feel like deleting the answer so I can delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

To select the element with text as **`Unwanted Calls (including do not call and spoofing)`** within the dropdown box adjacent to **Phone Issues** located within the [website](https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=39744) you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  #options.add_argument("--headless")
  #options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  #options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=39744")
  driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 400)")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Please select the issue that best describes your complaint.']//preceding::a[1]"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Please select the issue that best describes your complaint.']//preceding::select[@class='ae-select' and starts-with(@id, 'ae-request_custom_fields')]//option[contains(., 'Unwanted Calls')]"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Unwantedcalls]

Comment: It looks like I should delete the question. The community found it to be sub-par. Do you feel like deleting the answer so I can delete the question?